# Adding project on github only added one directory, and trying to push the other directories is giving me issues

Tags: git, github, version-control

So I tried to share a project on github (after deleting it multiple times). It shared, but it only shared one directory. We will call it /template-code

I have other directories present in the project that contain the actual code I ultimately need to commit. We will call this /my-submission.

In github, only /template-code is present. None of /my-submission is. If I run a git log on /mysubmission, it contains the recent commit messages appropriately. However, it's still not on github. When I try to push, I get the following:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepo_2'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I run a git pull, I am told it is already up to date. Any idea how to remedy this? At this point I'm simply worried about overriding my local changes, so I'm trying to do this right :)

Comment: What about `git merge remotes/<remote name>/<remote branch>`?

Comment: @dan1st So I just ran a git push --force, and that got my directory I wanted up, but removed all other directories. Let me give that a shot

Comment: Just create one directory with all the directories you want to check in and run the git commands, there

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the current history of commits, simply make sure that you have locally:

```
myProject
  template-code
  my-submission
```

In the myProject folder:

```
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "Import full project, template and submission"
```

Then force push it:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepo_2
git push --force -u origin master
```